# SQL Server : adding more than 1 where clause for a single column on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Project` table and each project has multiple employees connected to it with different roles. I want to be able to filter the projects with more than one employee for example I want to get all the projects where "Janet" is the Sales Rep and "Mark" is the Project manager... This is what I tried so far and it doesn't show the expected results:

```
SELECT 
    p_Empl.First_Name, 
    p_Resources.cRole, p_Resources.Project_ID, 
    p_Resources.Resources_ID, p_Resources.Empl_ID, 
    p_Project.Project_ID AS Expr1, 
    p_Project.ProjectNum, 
    p_Empl.Last_Name
FROM  
    p_Project 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    p_Resources ON p_Project.Project_ID = p_Resources.Project_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    p_Empl ON p_Resources.Empl_ID = p_Empl.ID
WHERE 
    p_Project.Project_ID IN (SELECT p_Project.Project_ID
                             FROM p_Project 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN p_Client ON p_Project.Client_ID = p_Client.Client_ID
                             WHERE p_Project.Project_ID IN (SELECT p_Project.Project_ID
                                                            FROM p_Project 
                                                            INNER JOIN p_Resources ON p_Resources.Project_ID = p_Project.Project_ID
                                                            INNER JOIN p_Empl ON p_Resources.Empl_ID = p_Empl.ID
                                                            WHERE p_Empl.First_Name = 'Mark'
                                                              AND p_Resources.cRole = 'Sales Manager'
                                                            ORDER BY p_Project.Project_ID)
                              AND p_Project.Project_ID IN (SELECT p_Project.Project_ID
                                                           FROM p_Project 
                                                           INNER JOIN p_Resources ON p_Resources.Project_ID = p_Project.Project_ID
                                                           INNER JOIN p_Empl ON p_Resources.Empl_ID = p_Empl.ID
                                                           WHERE p_Empl.First_Name = 'Janet'
                                                             AND p_Resources.cRole = 'Project Manager'
                                                          ORDER BY p_Project.Project_ID)
                             GROUP BY 
                                 p_Project.Project_ID, p_Client.ClientName, p_Project.ProjectName, p_Project.ProjectNum
                             ORDER BY 
                                 p_Client.ClientName, p_Project.ProjectName, p_Project.ProjectNum 
                             OFFSET (25 * (1)) ROWS FETCH NEXT (25) ROWS ONLY)
```

I'm very new to SQL and to programming altogether. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two subqueries. Use only one with `OR` between the different group of filters and use aggregation on projectId to use having clause to make sure both are present in for that projectId.

```
select p_Empl.First_Name,
    p_Resources.cRole,
    p_Resources.Project_ID,
    p_Resources.Resources_ID,
    p_Resources.Empl_ID,
    p_Project.Project_ID as Expr1,
    p_Project.ProjectNum,
    p_Empl.Last_Name
from p_Project
left outer join p_Resources on p_Project.Project_ID = p_Resources.Project_ID
left outer join p_Empl on p_Resources.Empl_ID = p_Empl.ID
where p_Project.Project_ID in (
        select p_Project.Project_ID
        from p_Project
        left outer join p_Client on p_Project.Client_ID = p_Client.Client_ID
        where p_Project.Project_ID in (
                select p_Project.Project_ID
                from p_Project
                inner join p_Resources on p_Resources.Project_ID = p_Project.Project_ID
                inner join p_Empl on p_Resources.Empl_ID = p_Empl.ID
                where (p_Empl.First_Name = 'Mark'
                    and p_Resources.cRole = 'Sales Manager')
                    or (p_Empl.First_Name = 'Janet'
                    and p_Resources.cRole = 'Project Manager')
                group by p_Project.Project_ID
                having count(distinct p_Empl.First_Name + p_Resources.cRole) = 2
                )
        group by p_Project.Project_ID,
            p_Client.ClientName,
            p_Project.ProjectName,
            p_Project.ProjectNum
        order by p_Client.ClientName,
            p_Project.ProjectName,
            p_Project.ProjectNum OFFSET(25 * (1)) ROWS fetch next (25) ROWS only
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want both conditions to be met. Not either or. This query gives me all the projects where at least one of the conditions are met. I want to get all the projects where Janet is the Sales Manager "and" Mark is the Project manager.

Comment: @BYG - In that case, you can use aggregation to ensure both are present in the project. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a billion for your answer! This is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *projects*, then I would use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.Project_ID , p.ProjectNum
FROM p_Project p JOIN
     p_Resources r
     ON p.Project_ID = r.Project_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     p_Empl e
     ON r.Empl_ID = e_Empl.ID
WHERE (e.First_Name = 'Mark' AND r.cRole = 'Sales Manager') OR
      (e.First_Name = 'Janet' AND r.cRole = 'Project Manager')
GROUP BY p.Project_ID , p.ProjectNum
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.First_Name) = 2;
```

If you want all the detail for the projects, I would do something like this:

```
WITH per as (
      SELECT . . .   -- all the columns you want
      FROM p_Project p JOIN
           p_Resources r
           ON p.Project_ID = r.Project_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
           p_Empl e
           ON r.Empl_ID = e_Empl.ID
     )
SELECT per.*
FROM per
WHERE per.Projecdt_Id IN (SELECT per2.ProjectId
                          FROM per per2
                          WHERE (per2.First_Name = 'Mark' AND per2.cRole = 'Sales Manager') OR
                                (per2.First_Name = 'Janet' AND per2.cRole = 'Project Manager')
                          GROUP BY p.Project_ID 
                          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.First_Name) = 2  
                         );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want both conditions to be met. Not either or. This query gives me all the projects where at least one of the conditions are met. I want to get all the projects where Janet is the Sales Manager "and" Mark is the Project manager.

Comment: @BYG . . . No it doesn't.  The combination of the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` clause returns only projects where both those conditions are true.

Comment: you're right! I didn't realize. Thanks a lot for your help.